# What is the difference in nuance by using から and between に with the passive verb?

Tags: grammar, particle-に, particle-から

Example 1:

> **先生 に 叱られた**

Example 2:

> **先生 から 叱られた**

Do these sentences imply the same meaning or no ?

***i.e I was scolded by my teacher***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sentences mean the same thing specifically in the case of 叱れる, but に and から are not always interchangeable in passive-form sentences. The default particle to use in passive constructions is に - it is used to mark the agent from which something is being done. There are times when you can use から instead, such in cases where abstract, non-physical actions are involved. That is why both 先生に叱られた and 先生から叱られた are possible. I don't think there is any difference in nuance between the two. から is usually only used instead of に in sentences where there are two instances of に since that can make a sentence somewhat confusing. There are some examples of that in the first link below.

More info on passive forms:

- https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-grammar/japanese-passive-form/
- http://www.guidetojapanese.org/causepass.html
- https://www.tofugu.com/japanese-grammar/verb-passive-form-rareru/

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a delicate difference.
For me, から have a nuance that one keeps distance from the teacher.